# RecyclerViewLayoutManager null object reference

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

The application crashes with an error stating that the Recyclerview is being called on a null object. However I can't seem to pinpoint what is causing this issue. Any help would be very much appreciated. If anymore code is needed, do let me know and I'll edit it in.

Logcat error:

```
2019-10-30 23:59:15.235 10878-10878/com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3, PID: 10878
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3/com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.view.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2861)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2943)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1630)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.view.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7032)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2943) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1630) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.view;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.database.DatabaseHelper;
import com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.database.model.Note;
import com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.utils.MyDividerItemDecoration;
import com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.utils.RecyclerTouchListener;

import com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.R;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private NotesAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<Note> notesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TextView noNotesView;

    private DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        noNotesView = findViewById(R.id.empty_notes_view);

        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        notesList.addAll(db.getAllNotes());

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showNoteDialog(false, null, -1);
            }
        });

        mAdapter = new NotesAdapter(this, notesList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MyDividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, 16));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        toggleEmptyNotes();

        /**
         * On long press on RecyclerView item, open alert dialog
         * with options to choose
         * Edit and Delete
         * */
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this,
                recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                showActionsDialog(position);
            }
        }));
    }

    /**
     * Inserting new note in db
     * and refreshing the list
     */
    private void createNote(String note) {
        // inserting note in db and getting
        // newly inserted note id
        long id = db.insertNote(note);

        // get the newly inserted note from db
        Note n = db.getNote(id);

        if (n != null) {
            // adding new note to array list at 0 position
            notesList.add(0, n);

            // refreshing the list
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            toggleEmptyNotes();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updating note in db and updating
     * item in the list by its position
     */
    private void updateNote(String note, int position) {
        Note n = notesList.get(position);
        // updating note text
        n.setNote(note);

        // updating note in db
        db.updateNote(n);

        // refreshing the list
        notesList.set(position, n);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);

        toggleEmptyNotes();
    }

    /**
     * Deleting note from SQLite and removing the
     * item from the list by its position
     */
    private void deleteNote(int position) {
        // deleting the note from db
        db.deleteNote(notesList.get(position));

        // removing the note from the list
        notesList.remove(position);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

        toggleEmptyNotes();
    }

    /**
     * Opens dialog with Edit - Delete options
     * Edit - 0
     * Delete - 0
     */
    private void showActionsDialog(final int position) {
        CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[]{"Edit", "Delete"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose option");
        builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0) {
                    showNoteDialog(true, notesList.get(position), position);
                } else {
                    deleteNote(position);
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }


    /**
     * Shows alert dialog with EditText options to enter / edit
     * a note.
     * when shouldUpdate=true, it automatically displays old note and changes the
     * button text to UPDATE
     */
    private void showNoteDialog(final boolean shouldUpdate, final Note note, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        View view = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.note_dialog, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderUserInput = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilderUserInput.setView(view);

        final EditText inputNote = view.findViewById(R.id.note);
        TextView dialogTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
        dialogTitle.setText(!shouldUpdate ? getString(R.string.lbl_new_note_title) : getString(R.string.lbl_edit_note_title));

        if (shouldUpdate && note != null) {
            inputNote.setText(note.getNote());
        }
        alertDialogBuilderUserInput
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(shouldUpdate ? "update" : "save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {
                                dialogBox.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilderUserInput.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Show toast message when no text is entered
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inputNote.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter note!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                } else {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }

                // check if user updating note
                if (shouldUpdate && note != null) {
                    // update note by it's id
                    updateNote(inputNote.getText().toString(), position);
                } else {
                    // create new note
                    createNote(inputNote.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Toggling list and empty notes view
     */
    private void toggleEmptyNotes() {
        // you can check notesList.size() > 0

        if (db.getNotesCount() > 0) {
            noNotesView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            noNotesView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

NotesAdapter.java

```
package com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.view;


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.calendar.database.Calendar;
import com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.database.model.Note;

import com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.R;


public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Note> notesList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView note;
        public TextView dot;
        public TextView timestamp;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            note = view.findViewById(R.id.note);
            dot = view.findViewById(R.id.dot);
            timestamp = view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        }
    }


    public NotesAdapter(Context context, List<Note> notesList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.notesList = notesList;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.note_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Note note = notesList.get(position);

        holder.note.setText(note.getNote());

        // Displaying dot from HTML character code
        holder.dot.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));

        // Formatting and displaying timestamp
        holder.timestamp.setText(formatDate(note.getTimestamp()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notesList.size();
    }

    /**
     * Formatting timestamp to `MMM d` format
     * Input: 2018-02-21 00:15:42
     * Output: Feb 21
     */
    private String formatDate(String dateStr) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = fmt.parse(dateStr);
            SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d");
            return fmtOut.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

activity_notes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.view.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main_timetable" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

note_list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.view.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main_timetable" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main_timetable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activities.TimetableActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_white_24"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="339dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="546dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Post the @layout/content_main_timetable layout

Comment: @MichaelStoddart Added the layout file for your reference.

Comment: Managed to fix it thanks to you. What happened was when i was refactoring , one of the includes in the activity_notes.xml file got changed to include an xml file meant for another module. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `RecyclerView` in your layout file, so when you call `findViewById`, no view is found, and your `recyclerView` is null, which is the reason for your null pointer exception.

In content_main_timetable did you mean `RecyclerView` instead of `ViewPager`? Replacing the view pager with a recycler view called recycler_view would fix your problem.

Comment: As stated in the comment above, I somehow managed to change the include statement in activity_notes to include an incorrect xml file which did not contain the recyclerview. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Your layout doesn't have a recyclerView. Which is why, findViewById returns a null. Your recyclerView is null, so you can't really set a layoutmanager on it. Fix your activity layout to include a recyclerview.

Comment: Managed to get it working now. Thank you so much.